# HashMap value sent in to bean class java

Tags: java, hashmap

i stucked in a major problem,  i have a map called hash map like

```
{19434={ballsdone=184, ballsdone2=343, comment=Lancs trail by 83 runs, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-7074Lancashire.png, flag2=Img-2216Yorkshire.png, id=19434, id1=8, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 1, matchid=19434, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=109, score2=192, series_id=64, series_name=County Championship Division One 2018, status=1, t1=LANCS, t2=YORKS, target=206, team1=Lancashire, team2=Yorkshire, title=LANCS vs YORKS, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - Old Trafford, Manchester, wicket=10, wicket2=10}, 
 19435={ballsdone=324, ballsdone2=252, comment=Sur lead by 11 runs, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-6552Nottinghamshire.png, flag2=Img-8581Surrey.png, id=19435, id1=9, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 1, matchid=19435, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=210, score2=221, series_id=64, series_name=County Championship Division One 2018, status=1, t1=NOTTS, t2=SUR, target=563, team1=Nottinghamshire, team2=Surrey, title=NOTTS vs SUR, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - Trent Bridge, Nottingham, wicket=10, wicket2=1}, 
 19436={ballsdone=576, ballsdone2=0, comment=Day 1: Stumps, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-7101Somerset.png, flag2=, id=19436, id1=10, inning=1, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 1, matchid=19436, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=324, score2=0, series_id=64, series_name=County Championship Division One 2018, status=1, t1=SOM, t2=, target=, team1=Somerset, team2=, title=WORCS vs SOM, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - New Road, Worcester, wicket=9, wicket2=0}, 
 19522={ballsdone=325, ballsdone2=246, comment=Warks trail by 84 runs, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-1634Middlesex.png, flag2=Img-5585Warwickshire.png, id=19522, id1=11, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 2, matchid=19522, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=236, score2=152, series_id=65, series_name=County Championship Division Two 2018, status=1, t1=MDX, t2=WARKS, target=182, team1=Middlesex, team2=Warwickshire, title=MDX vs WARKS, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - Lord's, London, wicket=10, wicket2=4}, 
 19523={ballsdone=227, ballsdone2=331, comment=LEIC lead by 45 runs, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-7731Kent.png, flag2=Img-5506Leicestershire.png, id=19523, id1=12, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 2, matchid=19523, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=104, score2=149, series_id=65, series_name=County Championship Division Two 2018, status=1, t1=Kent , t2=LEIC, target=415, team1=Kent, team2=Leicestershire, title=KENT vs LEIC, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - St Lawrence Ground, Canterbury, wicket=10, wicket2=6}, 
 19524={ballsdone=574, ballsdone2=0, comment=Day 1: Stumps, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-7692Gloucestershire.png, flag2=Img-9899Durham.png, id=19524, id1=13, inning=1, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 2, matchid=19524, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=315, score2=0, series_id=65, series_name=County Championship Division Two 2018, status=1, t1=GLOUCS, t2=DUR, target=, team1=Gloucestershire, team2=Durham, title=GLOUCS vs DUR, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - College Ground, Cheltenham, wicket=7, wicket2=0}, 
 19525={ballsdone=449, ballsdone2=114, comment=NOR trail by 186 runs, date=22 July 2018 , 03:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-9861Derbyshire.png, flag2=Img-5442Northamptonshire.png, id=19525, id1=14, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 2, matchid=19525, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=260, score2=74, series_id=65, series_name=County Championship Division Two 2018, status=1, t1=DERBY, t2=NOR, target=457, team1=Derbyshire, team2=Northamptonshire, title=DERBY vs NOR, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - Queen's Park, Chesterfield, wicket=10, wicket2=3}, 
 19526={ballsdone=571, ballsdone2=0, comment=Day 1: Stumps, date=22 July 2018 , 06:30 PM, event_Id=, flag1=Img-2844Sussex.png, flag2=Img-25784_Glamorgan.png, id=19526, id1=15, inning=1, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=County Div 2, matchid=19526, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=327, score2=0, series_id=65, series_name=County Championship Division Two 2018, status=1, t1=SUS, t2=GLAM, target=, team1=Sussex, team2=Glamorgan, title=SUS vs GLAM, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - County Ground, Hove, wicket=10, wicket2=0}, 
 20165={ballsdone=486, ballsdone2=455, comment=RSA need 244 runs, date=20 July 2018 , 10:00 AM, event_Id=, flag1=IMG-0-201711220843449293.png, flag2=IMG-0-201712281139133480.png, id=20165, id1=2, inning=2, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=2nd Test, matchid=20165, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=275, score2=246, series_id=90, series_name=South Africa tour of Sri Lanka 2018, t1=SL, t2=RSA, target=303, team1=Sri Lanka, team2=South Africa, title=SL vs RSA, total_balls=540, type=0, userid=, venue=At - Sinhalese Sports Club, Colombo, wicket=5, wicket2=7}, 
 20481={ballsdone=0, ballsdone2=0, comment=Starts in 7 hrs 00 min, date=23 July 2018 , 07:15 PM, event_Id=, flag1=, flag2=, id=20481, id1=20, inning=1, market_Id=1.145815859, match_number=13th Match, matchid=20481, order=0, rate=, rate2=, rate_team=, score=0, score2=0, series_id=93, series_name=Tamil Nadu Premier League 2018, status=1, t1=LKK, t2=, target=, team1=Lyca Kovai Kings, team2=, title=RTW vs LKK, total_balls=120, type=0, userid=, venue=At - NPR College Ground, Dindigul, wicket=0, wicket2=0}}
```

and i have  one bean class also  where i wnat to set hask map value in to bean array list not i am not getting how can i do this i have tried like this

i have bean class with following object

```
public class CFLivematch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="comment")
    String comment;


    @Column(name="date")
    String date;

    @Column(name="flag1")
    String flag1;

    @Column(name="flag2")
    String flag2;

    @Column(name="inning")
    String inning;

    @Column(name="matchnumber")
    String matchnumber;

    @Column(name="t1")
    String t1;

    @Column(name="t2")
    String t2;

    @Column(name="team1")
    String team1;

    @Column(name="team2")
    String team2;

    @Column(name="totalballs")
    String totalballs;

    @Column(name="venue")
    String venue;

    @Column(name="wicket")
    String wicket;

    @Column(name="wicket2")
    String wicket2;

    @Column(name="score")
    String score;

    @Column(name="score2")
    String score2;

    @Column(name="target")
    String target;

    @Column(name="ballsdone2")
    String ballsdone2;

    @Column(name="ballsdone")
    String ballsdone;

    @Column(name="total_balls")
    String total_balls;


    @Column(name="rate")
    String rate;

    @Column(name="rate2")
    String rate2;

    @Column(name="title")
    String title;

    @Column(name="match_number")
    String match_number;

    @Column(name="series_id")
    String series_id;

    @Column(name="series_name")
    String series_name;

    @Column(name="order")
    String order;

    @Column(name="orstatusder")
    String status;

    @Column(name="type")
    String type;

    @Column(name="rate_team")
    String rate_team;

    @Column(name="market_Id")
    String market_Id;

    @Column(name="event_Id")
    String event_Id;


    @Column(name="addedtofirebase")
    String addedtofirebase;


    @Column(name="matchid")
    String matchid;

    @Transient
    String id1;

    @Transient
    String userid;
}
```

and i want to set that  that bean   object

i have on `ArrayList<CFLivematch>` 
could you please guys help me to out this.

Thanks

Comment: Please give some details, what is exactly the structure into the one you wnt to put your data ?

Comment: Hello, please read this article and reformulate your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Mate you forgot to share the piece of code

Comment: Hi all  edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Define your own input parser that will convert your input map in String format to java object type.

Another way is, if possible, get your input data in known format, e.g. json, and use json library to convert to your object.